# How to scrape data from another website which is built in AngularJS?

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, web-crawler

I have to get some specific data from another web page which is built in AngularJS.

### What I have done until now:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Method = "GET";
            response = request.GetResponse();
            reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8);
            result = reader.ReadToEnd();

            HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml(result);
```

It's not returning proper HTML and I suppose (after searching) that the site is returning 4 items but the page source shows only one item with this `{{item.name}}` type of syntax.

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `HttpWebRequest`, it will just return you the `HTML` template, it will not contain any data. Due to the nature of Angular, data binding happens later on using JavaScript.

I suggest you to use `WebBrowser` Control instead of HttpWebRequest for data scraping. Using `WebBrowser` you should be able to get the complete HTML after the $scope is initialized and data is added to the `DOM`.

To know more about how to use `WebBrowser` in ASP.NET you can check this [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/50544/Using-the-WebBrowser-Control-in-ASP-NET)